# Is there a possibility to write NaN values to a txt file as blank?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nan

I have the following df with columns:

```
    DueDate
0   <cbc:DueDate>2020-10-18</cbc:DueDate>
1   <cbc:DueDate>2020-01-08</cbc:DueDate>
2   NaN
3   NaN

     Streetname
0    <cbc:StreetName>Xerox GmbH</cbc:StreetName>            
1    <cbc:StreetName>Rompslomp.nl B.V.</cbc:StreetName>     
2    <cbc:StreetName>STAS picture</cbc:StreetName>          
3    <cbc:StreetName>Rex International B.V.</cbc:StreetName>

     PostalAdress
0    </cac:PostalAddress>
1    </cac:PostalAddress>
2    </cac:PostalAddress>
3    </cac:PostalAddress>
Name: PostalAdressClose, dtype: object
```

When I try to write this to a text file with the following code:

```
# xml document to be expanding with per row details
fac_doc_template = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.simplerinvoicing.org:si:si-ubl:ver1.1.x</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
  {fac_details}"""

# per row details
# todo: expand for all of the column values you want
fac_details_xml_template = """{Streetname}
  {DueDate}
  """
```

Then I iterate through the columns to write each to a seperate file with the following code:

```
def series_to_fac_details_xml(s):
    return fac_details_xml_template.format(**s)

for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    details = series_to_fac_details_xml(row)
    with open(fr"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output\{index}.xml", "w") as f:
        f.write(fac_doc_template.format(fac_details=details))
```

I have a problem.. I want the NaNs to be skipped when the value is NaN, however when I convert the NaNs to empty string using:

```
df3 = df3.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

I get whitelines in the output file..  The desired output is the immediate continuation of the next column write to the file (w/o whitespace) when an NaN occurs. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Let`s say you have this DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DueDate':   ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02',np.nan], 
                   'Streetname':['Main Street 1', 'Main Street 2', 'Main Street 3']
                  })

df
>>>
      DueDate     Streetname
0  2020-01-01  Main Street 1
1  2020-01-02  Main Street 2
2         NaN  Main Street 3
```

Than you can replace the `NaN`as you did with `df = df.replace(np.nan,'', regex=True)`.

Afterwards I suggest you perform an `apply` function and create a new Series to make your formation.

```
z = df.apply(lambda x: x['Streetname'] + ' ' + x['DueDate'], axis=1)
```

Later you can call `z.to_string(index=False)` and write this to your file. If you don't like the linebreaks you can replace them using `z.to_string(index=False).replace('\n','')` instead. I think this will clean up your code a bit, because you don't have to iterate over all lines.

I really hope this helps you and this answers your question.